# How to change context menu header text color?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How can I change the text color of a context menu's header?

Currently my styles.xml is as follows:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:contextPopupMenuStyle">@style/ContextMenuStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ContextMenuStyle"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu">
    </style>

    <style name="ContextMenuStyle.Header"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Header">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But gradle gives me lots of errors when building, like:
    app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:16:5-19:13: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Header'.

I obtained the style name TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Header from the Android source:
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml

What is the proper way to set the context menu's text color in styles.xml?

Comment: have you tried this <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item> ?

Comment: Thx. A few errors disappeared. But the error mentioned above (/main/res/values/styles.xml:16:5-19:13: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Header'.) is still showing up.